# How to stop chrome responsive inspector from changing the zoom?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When using the option "toggle device scrollbar" in the Chrome inspector, whenever you type a new width/height, the window zoom adjusts for that width/height automatically. This is an incredibly frustrating UI, as I don't want the zoom to adjust... ever. The only way to avoid this is by resizing the responsive window by dragging the side borders.

Is there a way to turn the auto zoom off?

My current version of chrome: Version 54.0.2840.98 (64-bit)

Comment: So... I am not sure what triggered the zoom to automatically switch when altering the width and height, but restarting the computer seems to have fixed the issue for now.

Comment: I am having this issue again. Has anyone had this issue? Whenever I adjust the page width/height, the zoom also adjusts.

Comment: Did you ever find the cause for this, I am experiencing the same issue and it is beyond annoying.

Comment: No luck, it seems to start/stop on it's own. I don't know what triggers it, and I don't see a setting to turn it off. I know that sometimes it will go away and work as it should.

Comment: It looks like the zoom triggers depending on the size of the main browser window. So if you make the main browser window larger, than the responsive window will have more space, and the zoom won't trigger as much.

Comment: This is annoying as hell!!

Answer (score 89):

I have had this issue a few times now. I'm unsure what causes it, but i've found that you can fix it by selecting `"Restore to defaults"` in the `Toggle device toolbar` menu.

[image: Screenshot here]

Comment: Just wanted to note that the menu mentioned above in the three dot menu in the top right of the window displaying the responsive view. It is not totally clear above, especially if you have the dev tool un-docked in their own window (screenshot above shows docked).

Comment: I find that works initially, but the fix does not persist.

Comment: In latest versions of Chrome the reset option can be found here: `Three dot menu - Settings - Preferences - Restore defaults and reload`

Comment: Still worked for me. I am not sure what @Optimae is saying about the menu item moving, because it is nearly the same as in the screenshot here. Remember to click the three dot menu in _dev tools_, not the one to the right of the search/url bar. You certainly don't want to reset all of Chrome's settings. (I mean, you really don't want to reset the dev tool's settings either, but that's better than the alternative with this bug.)

Comment: Didn't work for me - however @mad dog cadogen's answer below did work.

Comment: You can also hit ctrl + 0 on your keyboard and no need to reload the page.

Comment: Simply typing Ctrl+Shift+M in Chrome Devtools worked for me and disabled the Responsive View mode. I got this from https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode.

Answer (score 55):

**Here's how I finally managed to resolve this issue in 5 steps, I hope it helps:**

1. Click `"Toggle device toolbar"` to bring the toolbar up
   [image: image of toggle device toolbar icon]
2. Click the 3 dots on the right hand side of the device toolbar

[image: image of location of 3 dots]

3. Click the option `"Add device type"`.
4. This will add a new dropdown to the device toolbar. From there you can select `"Desktop (touch)"`
   [image: image of new device type dropdown]
5. Problem solved.

Comment: Doesn't do anything I'm afraid.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: This worked for me too (although, I did also "reset to defaults"). "Desktop" also works it seems. Thanks!

Comment: I had to also set the percentage back to 100%.   This still doesn't seem to be the way it was before I somehow enabled the responsive mode?

Comment: Simply typing Ctrl+Shift+M in Chrome Devtools worked for me and disabled the Responsive View mode. I got this from https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode.

Comment: This issue has happened to me several times over the years. The "reset defaults" method usually works. However, today that method had no effect. Turns out same issue suddenly started today in Brave, after several hours of normal operation. But checking in Chrome--it had become infected with the same problem. So I tried this "add device type" method for Brave. It worked.

Answer (score 16):

To disable scaling and zooming you must add this inside the `<head>` tag:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

The minimal `<meta>` tag (which doesn’t disable user-controlled scaling) is:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
```

It’s not a Chrome problem.

Comment: How do force scaling automatically for all browsers?

Comment: Shouldn't be downvoted – this solved it for me. I only set width and initial-scale.

Comment: It's a Chrome problem, because I was forced to Google this issue. I should not have had to.

Comment: This solution disables the zoom feature for all users, which is a real accessibility issue for people relying on it.

Comment: This does not work, the dev tools still zooms the page. For example when you have a screen smaller than 1920 and you set 1920 width it zooms under 100% to fit.

Comment: This is a Chrome DevTools issue, you shouldn't have to change your HTML to enable/disable options for it. Clicking the vertical ... on the top right, then Reset to defaults solves it in Chrome 118.0.5993.89

Answer (score 11):

I asked this question a long time ago, and today I noticed a change in Chrome. I am not sure when this was introduced, since I haven't used the responsive options as much, but on Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit) there's now an option called "Auto-adjust zoom", and it was checked (enabled) by default. I unchecked it, and now the zoom will no longer change when the screen is resized.

You can access this option by clicking on "100%" next to the screen size, in the responsive screen. See image below:

[image]

Comment: I noticed this same thing last night and toggling that setting did nothing. I have a feeling that this is a bug, but that the setting you mention _should_ always work the way you've experienced. So for those that are not experiencing this bug, and just have that setting enabled, this ought to work. (Incidentally, using the steps outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45695394/1386201) worked.)

Comment: I noticed it too but it didnt do anything for me either!

Comment: The **Auto-adjust zoom** preference was added to the *zoom* drop down menu in early 2018 with the release of Chrome 66.

Comment: It still auto-adjusts with this option enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 4):

I've reported this bug to Chromium.

Here's the link:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1129880#c2

I've found the reason why this happens as well as a "mitigation": set the height to empty string: ""

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me, although perhaps you could reword `set the height to empty string: ""` to just `empty the height field` since that's more clear (imo). Unfortunately the bug report seems to be inactive now.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked for me:

1. F12 (open developer tools)
2. Ctrl + Shift + M (toggle device toolbar)
3. Click the top right three dot menu
4. Click Add Device Type
5. On the top bar, A "Mobile" or "Desktop" dropdown list should appear
6. Chances are "Mobile" is selected, switch it to "Desktop"

The auto-zoom should now go away, when you are in responsive mode and shrink the width of the viewport/device...

Comment: Simply typing Ctrl+Shift+M in Chrome Devtools worked for me and disabled the Responsive View mode.   I got this from https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/, and the found this answer was the closest to my answer.

Comment: This worked for me, just make sure that, you need to switch to toolbar. Kambbom ! Done

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is definitely doing something 'heuristically' and I'm pretty sure there are some bugs.

When using the 'responsive mode' (so I can drag the width back and forth) below around 320px the whole page starts scaling down. This makes sense as a default since there are basically no devices below that width and most content looks awful if it's allowed to fend for itself at such small sizes.

My original viewport settings were:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

The problem with that was there's nothing in the Chrome UI to constrain the minimum width to 320px (nobody needs to be designing for below that) and if you're dragging back and forth quickly then you'll inevitably end up with a width of say 169px. See the screenshot below to see how much of a mess I got in.

The height of my menu bar is 50px so it's clear that it *is* being scaled down. Unfortunately the rendering engine just seems to get confused and my buttons end up overflowing and making a huge mess. Even if I resize to greater than 320px it still stays confused and I have to refresh the page.

[image]

The important part of the accepted answer is the `minimum-scale=1.0` which prevents this scaling at low screen widths.

That's the key part to add to fix the issue and I can't see any reason to not have that.

Answer (score 0):

As of now you can go to device toolbar then click **Responsive** here:
[image]

Then in the **Responsive** dropdown go to **Edit ...** and add the resolution you want.

[image]

Then you can select your custom one from the options and zoom and it will stay the same resolution!

Answer (score 0):

after alot of searching about this problem,i figured out that probably it's a browser's bug...
even tho there's a solution for this that works 100% with no problem
here's the fix for this problem :

1. open devtools
2. open "Settings"

[image]

3. Go to "Devices"

[image]

4. click "Add custom device"

[image]

5. set the sizes you want with and set a name for this device then click "add"

[image]

6. you can see your new device in the list , this way the zoom will stay 100% and fix the issue for you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue and I realised it was because my actual browser window was not big enough to incorporate the size without zooming. May just be me, but thought I would share just in case.

Answer (score -1):

1. Click F12
2. In the right, top corner, near to chrome cross sign click on "Customize and control DevTools" kebab menu.
3. Click settings
4. Click Preferences
5. At the bottom, Click Restore defaults and reload
6. Make sure that you extensions will be removed.

Answer (score -2):

under zoom menu in responsive window > auto adjust zoom must get disabled

Comment: The auto-adjust zoom does not seem to do anything.

Answer (score -2):

Change Dock side to **Undock into separate window** as shown in the picture below:

[image]