# How to handle window resize for displaying canvas for mobile devices with devicepixelratio

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am trying to handle window resize event for a javascript canvas application.

<strike>When I change the width on browser it seems to work fine, but if I open device toolbar and change the width, the width doesn't change sticks to 980, though the height changes. And the rendered objects get much smaller.</strike>

According to this [How to stop chrome responsive inspector from changing the zoom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810720/how-to-stop-chrome-responsive-inspector-from-changing-the-zoom), now width change when I resize.

My new problem is the rendered objects still looks smaller on resize. It is related to `window.devicePixelRatio`.

For example If use this code to set the dimensions used to draw objects:

```
  this.width = displayWidth;
  this.height = displayHeight;
```

things render normally initially, and much smaller on resize.

If I change this code to this:

```
  this.width = displayWidth * devicePixelRatio;
  this.height = displayHeight * devicePixelRatio;
```

Things render much larger initially, but if I have the same code on resize, things render normal.

I also have this somewhere in:

```
canvasContext.scale(pixelRatio, pixelRatio);
```

Canvas javascript:

```
export default function Canvas(element) {

  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

  element.append(canvas);
  const displayWidth = canvas.clientWidth,
        displayHeight = canvas.clientHeight,
        devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

  this.pixelRatio = devicePixelRatio;


  this.width = displayWidth;
  this.height = displayHeight;

  canvas.width = displayWidth * devicePixelRatio;
  canvas.height = displayHeight * devicePixelRatio;

  this.aspect = this.width / this.height;

  this.canvas = canvas;

  this.bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

  // called on `window.onresize` event
  this.resize = () => {

    const displayWidth = canvas.clientWidth,
          displayHeight = canvas.clientHeight,
          pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

    this.pixelRatio = pixelRatio;
    this.width = displayWidth;
    this.height = displayHeight;

    canvas.width = displayWidth * pixelRatio;
    canvas.height = displayHeight * pixelRatio;

    this.aspect = this.width / this.height;

    this.bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

  };

};
```

css:

```
#app canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;

  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;

  transform: translate(-50%, -25%);

  image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was when it's resized, the canvas context lost it's scale properties, so I had to call scale again.

```
  ctx.scale(pixelRatio, pixelRatio);
  _canvas.addResizeListener(() => {
    ctx.scale(pixelRatio, pixelRatio);
  });
```