# Mobile menu enlarging whole site in HTML

Tags: html, sass, gulp

I'm making my first site with gulp.

I'm working with a mobile menu. When I click it, I want it to translate to the right. It works fine.

The problem is that when it goes right it enlarges the whole site, I even tried with `overflow:hidden` but it didn't work. Among the others I also tried to make `display:none`, but it didn't work either.

Here you can see the problem:

[image]

Can anybody help please? [Here is the link](https://github.com/PatrycjaSzajna/sell-more) to the repo.

Comment: Does this work the same way without the dev-tools opened ? It's not really gulp related question. I think that it might be a zoom triggered by the browser. I can see that You are simulating the mobile view

Comment: You are right. Closed dev tools. Made small browser window -> problem is not here.
Why dev tools is showing this menu? In other websites with a similar hidden mobile menu, it is hidden also with dev tools open. It should not enlarge the browser window. Do you have any idea how to fix that, so that I can easily develop the mobile using the dev tools simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Simple workaround is to change `transform: translateX(170px);` to `transform: translateY(-400px);` on .page-nav with 840px breakpoint.
This is where the issue comes from.

Comment: nice, that works, and I can leave it like this. However do you have any idea how to make it hide to the right? I tried also on other computeres with brand new chrome, and it's exactly the same.

Comment: Here is the example https://jsfiddle.net/bp481cwL/ . In this case I use js but it very simple. I use `querySelector` to get element with class `.container`. Next I add event to it. Each click toggle class .alert-is-shown.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it might be a zoom triggered by the browser. I can see that You are simulating the mobile view. That's probably the reason why it happens.
I've never tried that but i found something like this -> [How to stop chrome responsive inspector from changing the zoom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810720/how-to-stop-chrome-responsive-inspector-from-changing-the-zoom)

take a look :)